# Multipart file upload using Postman and Spring : Object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: spring, http-post, postman, multipartform-data

**Situation**: I'm making a POST request to a Spring controller using Postman. There is a text JSON, and a Multipart file.

**Problem**: I get an error as follows:

```
Method [public java.lang.String com.dure.ivizard.core.datamanagement.export.controller.FileUploadAction.uploadFileHandler(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,java.lang.String)]
Resolved arguments: 
[0] [type=org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile] [value=org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@e421749]
[1] [type=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade] [value=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@725e9373]
[2] [type=java.lang.String] [value={
"userid":"1",               
"email":"admin@gmail.com"
}]
] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

**The input parameters are as follows:**

Key: inputdataJsonStr 
Type: String
Value: {"userid" : "1", "email" :"abc@gmail.com"

Key: file
Type: File
Value:

**Here is the Spring controller's declaration**:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/confirmUploadLocalAttrFile_new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String uploadConfirmLocalAttrHandler_new(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpSession session, @RequestParam String inputdataJsonStr){
```

Full stack trace is as follows:

```
2018-01-08 12:27:35 INFO  DureContextListenerImpl:85 - ********************Application conext set
2018-01-08 12:27:35 INFO  SimpleCORSFilter:24 - SimpleCORSFilter init
2018-01-08 12:27:35 INFO  DispatcherServlet:473 - FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 4026 ms
Jan 08, 2018 12:27:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/ivizard] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48]
Method [public java.lang.String com.dure.ivizard.core.datamanagement.export.controller.FileUploadAction.uploadConfirmLocalAttrHandler_new(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)]
Resolved arguments: 
[0] [type=org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile] [value=org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@b32dcc0]
[1] [type=java.lang.String] [value={
"dataformat":"1",
"userid":"1",
"datacategory": "2",
"countryid":"0",
"targetOrIndicatorId":"21",
"email":"admin@gmail.com"
}]
[2] [type=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade] [value=org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@67577440]
] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What's puzzling is that even simple POST requests with just a JSON parameter have stopped working, and give the same error.

Comment: Can you try rearranging the argument sequence ? e.g. `String uploadConfirmLocalAttrHandler_new(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam String inputdataJsonStr, HttpSession session)`

Comment: Hi Kedar. Tried your suggestion, but I'm getting the same error. Earlier the same thing used to work, so is it due to some upgrade or some settings changes I must do ?

Comment: Can you add full stacktrace ? It's difficult to say without it.

Comment: Added stack trace in the question.

Comment: Stacktrace looks pretty standard. The only other reason I can think of is JAR conflict. Did you recently updated spring version ? or Do you have JAR files of multiple versions of spring, in your classpath ?

Comment: We did not update the Spring version. The JARs being used are spring-aop-3.2.6.RELEASE, spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE, spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE, spring-context-support-3.2.6.RELEASE, spring-core-3.2.6.RELEASE, spring-expression-3.2.6.RELEASE, spring-jdbc-3.2.6.RELEASE, and spring-security-config-3.1.4.RELEASE (aspect, core and web are also the same version i.e. 3.1.4).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162721/discussion-between-kedar-joshi-and-abhishek).

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/confirmUploadLocalAttrFile_new", method = 
RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String uploadConfirmLocalAttrHandler_new(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile 
file, HttpSession session, @RequestParam("jsonStr") String inputdataJsonStr){
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It worked by simply copying the controller and the entire function **as it was** to another file.

How did it work ? Why did it work ? These questions will be answered by God when we go to Heaven.